# saving form options

Tags: visualforce

I have created to forms and i am trying to save selected options of form in there objects can you provide some help my code is like; what logic should be used in save button

page--

```
<apex:page controller="SurveyFormController" sidebar="false">    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Survey Form">
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!displayradioButtonsValue}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!displayItems}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Display Form" action="{!selected}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:outputPanel title="Customer Form">
                <apex:outputPanel id="customerForm">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Customer Form" rendered="{!displayCustomerFormOrStudentForm='CustomerForm'}">
                    <apex:outputText value="How effective is the learning in Company?"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" > 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="How are the facilities in the Company?" />
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="How are the colleagues in Company?"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="Is Company helping you to grow your carrer?"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel title="Student Form">
                <apex:outputPanel id="studentForm" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Student Form" rendered="{!displayCustomerFormOrStudentForm='StudentForm'}">
                    <apex:outputText value="How effective is the teaching in University?"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" > 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="How are the facilities in the University?"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="How are the teachers in University?"/>
                        <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

                    <apex:outputText value="Is University helping you to grow your carrer?"/>
                        <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Extremelly Well" itemValue="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Quite Well" itemValue="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Moderately  Well" itemValue="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Slighty Well" itemValue="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Not at all Well" itemValue="5"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller---

```
public class SurveyFormController
{
    private String radioButtonsValue;

    private List<SelectOption> items;

    private String selectedCustomerOrStudent;

    Student__c si;

    Customer__c ci;

    public String displayradioButtonsValue
    {
        get
        {
            return radioButtonsValue;
        }
        set
        {
            radioButtonsValue=value;
        }
    }

    public List<SelectOption> displayItems
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items=value;
        }
    }

    public String displayCustomerFormOrStudentForm
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedCustomerOrStudent;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedCustomerOrStudent=value;
        }
    }

    public SurveyFormController()
    {
        items=new List<SelectOption>();
        items.add(new SelectOption('Customer','Customer'));
        items.add(new SelectOption('Student','Student'));

    }

    public SurveyFormController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {

        si=(Student__c)controller.getRecord();
        ci=(Customer__c)controller.getRecord();

    }

    public pageReference selected()
    {
        if(radioButtonsValue=='Customer')
        {
            selectedCustomerOrStudent='CustomerForm';
        }
        else if(radioButtonsValue=='Student')
        {
            selectedCustomerOrStudent='StudentForm';
        }

        PageReference pageRef=new PageReference('/apex/WrapperTestPage');

        return pageRef;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        if(radioButtonsValue=='Customer')
        {
            try         
            {            

            }        
                catch (DMLException c)         
            {

            }
        }        
        else if(radioButtonsValue=='Student')
        {
            insert si;
        }
    }
}
```